# Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ with Galois group $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ramification

Denote by $\mathbb{Q}_p$ the $p$-adic completion of the integers, i.e. with respect to the valuation $|x|=p^{-ord_p(x)}$. My question is, how do we find, and classify explicitly, all the field extensions $\mathbb{Q}_p\subset L$ with Galois group $G(L/\mathbb{Q}_p)=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: $\Bbb Q_p$, for $p>2$, has only three quadratic extensions, because $| \Bbb Q_p^{\times}/\Bbb Q_p^{\times \, 2}|=4$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Kummer theory, such extensions bijects with nontrivial elements of $\mathbb Q_p^\times/(\mathbb Q_p^\times)^2$. Explicitly, $a\ne 1\in\mathbb Q_p^\times/(\mathbb Q_p^\times)^2$ corresponds to $\mathbb Q_p(\sqrt a)$.

The group can be described via the following exact sequence, for $p>2$:
$$1\to \mathbb Z_p^\times/(\mathbb Z_p^\times)^2\cong\mathbb F_p^\times/(\mathbb F_p^\times)^2\to \mathbb Q_p^\times/(\mathbb Q_p^\times)^2\xrightarrow v\mathbb Z/2\to 0,$$
so $\mathbb Q_p^\times/(\mathbb Q_p^\times)^2\cong(\mathbb Z/2)^2$.

Comment: Also, for $p = 2$, we have $\mathbb{Q}_2^\times/(\mathbb{Q}_2^\times)^2 \cong (\mathbb{Z}/2)^3$, so the picture is similar but with 7 quadratic extensions instead of 3.